# Event notification on new e-mail in IBM Domino

Tags: lotus-domino

Is it possible to subscribe to mail events on an IBM Domino server?

I need a service similar to the one provided by [Microsoft Exchange Event Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579128%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx), where you can subscribe to events and get notified when there are changes - eg. arrival of a new e-mail. I need the solution to be server side, since I can't rely on users having their client running.

Comment: What's the reason for closing this question? Can it be closed without any reason?

Comment: This question is on topic. He wants to know if there is a service available in Domino that would be similar to the subscription services (push, pull, and streaming) that are part of Microsoft Exchange Web Services.  The answer, AFAIK, is that there is no equivalent web service included in Domino.  however there are various options available, including creating your own web service. This question should be re-opened to facilitate discussion of the available APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as per my comment above, there is no pre-packaged equivalent to the push, pull and streaming subscription services that EWS supports.  A Notes client can get notifications via Notes RPC protocol, and there's also obviously some technology in IBM's Notes Traveler mobile product, but nothing that I'm aware of as a pre-packed web service or even as a notifications API. You would have to build it.  There are a variety of ways you could go about it.

For push or streaming subscriptions, one way would be with a Notes C API plugin using the Extension Manager, running on the server and monitoring the mailboxes.  You might be able to use a DSAPI plugin into Domino's HTTP stack to manage the incoming connections and feed the data out to subscribers, but honestly I have no idea if Domino's HTTP stack can handle the persistent connections that are implied in the subscription model.  Alternatively, the  Extension Manager plugin  could quickly send the data over to code written in any other language that you want, running on any web stack that. Of course, you'll have to deal with security through all the linked-together parts.

For pull subscriptions, I guess it's really more of a polling archiecture, with state saved somewhere so that only changes since the last call will be delivered.  You have any number of options for that.  You could use Domino's built-in HTTP server, obviously, so you could write your own Domino-hosted web service for this. You could also use the Domino Data Service, which is a REST API, to do this -- with all necessary state information being stored on the client-side. (On quick look, I don't see a good option for getting all new docs since a specified date-time via Domino Data Service, but it might be possible.)

I do worry a bit about scalability of any custom solution for this. My understanding is that Microsoft has quite a bit of caching and optimization in their services in order to address scale. Obviously, you can build whatever you need for that into your own web service, but it will likely add a lot of effort.

Comment: Thank you Richard, for your thorough explanation. It was just what I was looking for. And thank you for getting the question re-opened.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I have a problem: to extract/push user structure, notes and attachments from IBM Domino Server on any changes (create, delete, update). I've never worked with IBM Notes and Domino. Can I have a brief introduction from you on how to approach this problem? I write Python and Java. Had a little experience with C. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user674618  I don't think I can give you a brief introduction because it's not a brief topic, and that's true even for people who do have experince working with Notes and Domino. If you post specific questions (in line with the guidelines in the StackOverflow FAQ) and tag them for lotus-notes and lotus-domino, then I will see them. So will a lot of other people, and I'm sure that people will try to answer you.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Thank you! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086797/how-to-extract-data-from-lotus-domino-server) is my question.